# Logical Operators in Blue Prism Expressions - Logical NOT

Tags: vb.net, blueprism

When creating logical expressions, Blue Prism provides you with logical AND and logical OR. As far as I can tell, there is no availability to find the logical NOT of a flag. Can someone provide a solution for implementing the NOT operator in Blue Prism?

I am aware of DeMorgan's theorems but they are inconvenient and not intuitive for certain applications.

Edit: I suppose you could do something like `[flagName]<>True`. I would still like to hear from others if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Blue Prism does not provide a NOT operator, which is inconvenient. It is possible to work around this issue using some of the following ideas:

- Use `<>` instead of `=` if you are comparing two expressions.
- Use `[flag]<>True` or `[flag]=False` inside a expression.
- Create a flag with opposite meaning. For instance replace an [Empty] flag with a [NotEmpty] flag. The flag can be created using a **Calculation** stage with the `[flag]<>True` or `[flag]=False` expressions.
- Invert a **Decision** stage flow right clicking on the stage and selecting **Switch**.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in your edit, the best way to compare if something is not equivalent in Blue Prism would be to use the `<>` operator.

`1 <> 1` evaluates to `False (flag)`, and `1 <> 2` evaluates to `True (flag)`.

(Unfortunately, I don't have a hard documentation source.)